# Css selector nth sibling and stops if it encounters another parent class

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to have an nth sibling selector for the code below?

So far this is what I've done.

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr class="parent" path="0"></tr>
  <tr class="child" path="0,1"></tr>
  <tr class="child lastChild" path="0,2"></tr>

  <tr class="parent" path="1"></tr>
  <tr class="child" path="1,1"></tr>
  <tr class="child lastChild" path="1,2"></tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.parent:hover ~.childRow {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

**NOTE:**
I'm using React material table which is why the rows, even though one is the parent are on the same level. There were a few solutions to highlighting the row of the parent and the children, but it involves re-rendering which is quite an expensive operation, Hence why I'm trying to find a pure css solution.

The problem with this is that if I hover on the first parent, it also highlights the children of the second parent.

Maybe I should use the path attribute? Or is there a css selector that selects adjacent sibling from top to bottom, but stops as soon as it sees another "parent" class?

Is this even possible?

Another addition:

Would it help if the very last child can have an additiona class such as 'lastChild', as a sort of stopper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to overwrite the rules for the elements that follow a `.parent` which itself follows a `.parent:hover`.

Though this may not work for all rules, it will for most.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.child {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}
.parent:hover ~ .child {
  border-color: blue;
}
.parent:hover ~ .parent ~ .child {
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="parent" path="0"><td>parent 1 (hover me)</td></tr>
  <tr class="child"  path="0,1"><td>child 1.1</td></tr>
  <tr class="child"  path="0,2"><td>child 1.2</td></tr>

  <tr class="parent" path="1"><td>parent 2 (hover me)</td></tr>
  <tr class="child"  path="1,1"><td>child 2.1</td></tr>
  <tr class="child"  path="1,2"><td>child 2.2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I never thought to do it this way, thanks a lot! I will give the bounty after 20Hrs, since I can't give it now. But this solves my problem!

Comment: @GashioLee you may want to wait a bit more, maybe someone else will come with an even better solution.

Comment: Okay, I guess that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with React but this is what I know about plain CSS.

If all parents have 2 children exactly, then you can do this.

```css
.parent:nth-child(3n+1):hover ~.childRow {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: The number of children is unfortunately, dynamic